# How prove this $\frac{dr_{1}}{dr_{2}}=\frac{\cos{\theta_{1}}}{\cos{\theta_{2}}}$

Tags: differential-geometry

**Question:**

let two point $O_{1},O_{2}$, such
$$PO_{1}=r_{1},PO_{2}=r_{2}$$ There is a curve  $AB$ 
and the  point $P\in AB$,and EF is a tangent curve AB,and the tangent is $P$.
let
$$\angle CPE=\theta_{1},\angle DPE=\theta_{2}$$
show that
$$\dfrac{dr_{1}}{dr_{2}}=\dfrac{\cos{\theta_{1}}}{\cos{\theta_{2}}}$$

Thank you ,I fell this reslut is clearly,But I can't prove it.Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: I believe that the right-hand $r_1$ in your figure should be $r_2$. What do you mean by $dr_1 / dr_2$? Are you taking derivatives here? If so, perhaps I can reformulate your problem: Let $\gamma: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb R^2$ be a unit-speed curve not intersecting the line $O_1O_2$, and suppose $\gamma(0) = P$. Let 
$$
r_1(t)  = \| \gamma(t) - O_1 \| \\
\theta_1 = \frac{\cos^{-1} ( \gamma'(0) \cdot (\gamma(0) - O_1) )}{r_1(t)}
$$
and similarly for $r_2(t)$ and $\theta_2$ (using $O_2$ instead of $O_1$). Show that 
$$
\frac{r_1'(0)}{r_2'(0)} = \frac{\cos(\theta_1)}{\cos(\theta_2)}
$$
Is that right?

Comment: Yes,the figure right hand $r_{1}$ is $r_{2}$. and follow how prove it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hint: draw a more careful diagram using a ruler, and introduce a point P' which is a distance $ds$ along the tangent $EF$.  use the cosine rule in triangles $O_1PP'$ and $O_2PP'$, then subtract the results to eliminate $r_1^2$, $r_2^2$ and $ds^2$. take the limit so $dr_1^2$ and $dr_2^2 \rightarrow 0$ and you've nearly done.

Comment: Thank you,can you post full solution? Thank you

Comment: @math110, a ruler *and compass*.